# MATLAB - Callback after reparenting

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to transfer all graphical objects from one figure to another, by changing the object's 'parent'.

The problem begins when I try to execute the object's callbacks (in this case a pushbutton) after reparenting.

I suspect it has something to do with the object's callback handle, but I'm not quite sure how to solve this.

Any solutions?
Thanks!

Comment: Showing some code to illustrate your point would be nice.

Comment: Set(hbutton, 'parent', hfigure)

Comment: *face palm*... Yeah. Closing.

Comment: Don't be disrespectful. That's the code, and there's nothing more to add. I'm asking for help from someone who is familiar with the problem of callbacks not executing after reparenting.

Comment: Wasn't trying to be disrespectful.  I honestly thought there would be more code than that.  I figured it had to do with something else more than just setting the parent.  I'll retract my close vote, but I misinterpreted your answer as being condescending.  Now that I see that it really wasn't, then I apologize.